# NSNotification not reloading table data

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to reload a tableView when a user adds some data. Having a little trouble with this and not really sure where to go from here. I've printed out the data to confirm the action of creating adds to my array and it does. Confirmed the notification is sent using the debugger and tried to confirm it's on the main thread too.

**TeamModel**

```
class TeamModel {

// a type of team
typealias Team = (String, Int, Int, Int)

// current list of teams
var teamList : [Team] = [("Manchester", 2, 40, 11), ("Arsenal", 2, 45, 11)]

// adds a new team to the user's list of teams
func addTeamToDB(newTeam: Team) {
    teamList.append(newTeam)
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("reloadTeams", object: nil)

    }
}
```

My initial data is loaded in a TableView

**TeamViewController**

```
class TeamViewController: UITableViewController {

// pointer to table
@IBOutlet var table: UITableView!

// reference to team Model
let teams = TeamModel().teamList

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(reloadTableData(_:)), name: "reloadTeams", object: nil)
}

func reloadTableData(notification: NSNotification) {
    table.reloadData()
}
```

From this tableView I segue to another tableView to add a team, the data is added ok, but when I return to the tableViewController data doesn't change

**AddTeamController**

```
...
// get pointer to model
private var newTeam = TeamModel()

@IBAction func addTeamToDB(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    let newTeamInfo = (teamName.text!, numberOfPlayersSliderValue, periodLengthSliderValue, numberOfPlayersSliderValue)

    newTeam.addTeamToDB(newTeamInfo)

    // return back to nav controller
    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
} 
...
```

**updated**

So my understanding from @rmaddy was that I could use prepare segue. So this is my code additions and how I expected them to work.

**TeamViewController**

I tried something like this, which is fine in other languages, but appears you can't do it in swift.

```
let t = TeamModel()
let teams = t.teamList
```

That gives me the teams used in the TableView and also a property `t` to the instantiated model I was going to try and pass within the segue. This gives me the error `instance member t cannot be used on type TeamViewController`. My segue for reference also in the `TeamViewController` was:

```
    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "addTeamSegue"
    {
        if let destinationVC = segue.destinationViewController as? TeamDetailsViewController{
            // send data
            destinationVC.tt = t
        }
    }
}
```

And I created a property in the TeamDetailsViewController to be updated like so:

```
var tt : TeamModel?
```

That's there so I could run: `tt?.addTeamToDB(newTeamInfo)` from within my button action, that I call when I'm adding a new team to my model, as I understood that I needed the same reference to TeamModel rather than creating a new one. New to swift and types etc, so trying to get things straight in my head.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your `TeamViewController` and `AddTeamController` each have their own instance of `TeamModel`. They need to be referencing the same instance for this to work as intended.

If you present `AddTeamController` from `TeamViewController` then you should pass the existing `teams` value from the `TeamViewController` to the `AddTeamController` instead of having the `AddTeamController` create its own instance of `TeamModel`.

Comment: Oh ok, I wondered about that, dumb question from a beginner now: would that be a prepareToSegue method to pass the `teams` value over?

Comment: I believe that is one way. I don't use storyboards or segues so I'm not quite sure how that works but I think if you add a `TeamModel` property to `AddTeamController`, you should be able to set that property in `prepareToSegue`.

Comment: Could you show me, I've had a bash at it, but getting compile errors. Sure it's super simple too :S

Comment: Update your question with what you have tried and explain what issues you are having.

Comment: Yes, I've updated my question. Still getting used to compiled languages and swift

Comment: Introduced a singleton pattern in the end - Thanks